Why `cowplot` is not extracting the legend?
We have a data set like this
x = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
y = c("s", "n", "f", "s", "n", "f", "s", "n", "f")
z1 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 5)
z2 = c(11, 5, 5, 10, 14, 2, 2, 2, 15)
df = data.frame(x, z1 ,z2, y)

I give each letter label a color and would like to create one figure with two plots side by side with a common legend.
Here's what I did
colors = c("s" = "black", "n" = "red", "f" = "blue")

pl1 = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.factor(x), y = z1, fill = y), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors, labels = c("s", "n", "f"), labs(title = "label:")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

pl2 = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.factor(x), y = z2, fill = y), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors, labels = c("s", "n", "f"), labs(title = "label:")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

combined_legend <- cowplot::get_legend(pl1 + theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=14)))

final_plot = cowplot::plot_grid(
  pl1 + theme(legend.position = "none"),
  pl2 + theme(legend.position = "none"),
  nrow = 1,  
  align = "h",  
  axis = "tb"  
)

plot = cowplot::plot_grid(
  final_plot,
  combined_legend,
  ncol = 1,
  rel_heights = c(3, 0.5)
)

The problem is that pl1 and pl2 individually have their legends but plot doesn't have any and when I run combined_legend, I see this out put:
zeroGrob[NULL]

So it means there is something wrong with extracting the legend using cowplot?
What should I do?

See https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues/202. It is currently broken, but will be fixed. Some solutions in the thread.

In the mean time, you can use library(patchwork); pl1 + pl2 + plot_layout(guides = 'collect') & theme(legend.position = "bottom")
